# application background data synchronization service in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

how to create application Background Service in xamarin forms?
any Service always sync with azure database when application get internet connection.

Comment: You should do it in [platform specific way](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Xamarin doesn't have a cross platform wrapper for Background services, you have to implement them on each platform. The good news is that you can still have the business logic in a Xamarin PCL library. There is a very good article that describe the use of MessengerCenter to accomplish that.
check this out: http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/
source code: https://github.com/RobGibbens/XamarinFormsBackgrounding

In order to have your local db always in sync with the master on Azure you can:

1. use Azure Mobile Apps client SDK to work with DocumentDB. It allows sync on flat object. https://github.com/karolzak/Mobile-App-DocumentDB-OfflineSync-Sample
2. use CoachDB. it's specifically designed for sync and offline scenarios. CoachDB can be installed on Azure.
3. you can implement the sync by your own using background services